# Entity Framework Core on Windows IoT running on a RPi 3 (Console Application)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I successfully deployed a .NET Core Console Application to my Windows IoT running on a Raspberry Pi 3.

The application pulls data from a webservice and stores them in a database. I used Entity Framework Core for that.

When I start the deployed console application (.exe) through the remote powershell everything works except the access to my database running on Azure. When the application tries to read from the database it throws the following exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIInitialize(IntPtr pmo)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

There is no 'sni.dll' in the application folder.

Deployed the application using the 'win8-arm' runtime.

- netcoreapp2.0
- .NET Core 2.0 SDK (Runtime and tooling)

Any ideas what's wrong?

Update:

Copying the System.Data.SqlClient.dll (unix lib) and overriding the existent one in the application folder solved the issue. See answer below.

Comment: Have you tested your app on desktop?

Comment: I have, everything works with runtime win10-x64. I think there is no ARM version of "sni.dll", whatever this is..

Comment: What's you .Net Core version?

Comment: Used netcoreapp2.0 and the .NET Core 2.0 SDK (Tooling and Runtime) but also tried it with netcoreapp1.1 and the 1.0 SDK

Answer (score 1):

There is no native `sni.dll` library for ARM. (See [dotnet/corefx#9064](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9064))

I was hoping I could tell you how to use the fully-managed implementation of `System.Data.SqlClient` (the one that's used on Linux), but it unfortunately uses `System.Threading.Thread` which isn't available on UWP...

[Update1]
Wait, you're not using UWP. :) Try getting the app to use `%USERPROFILE%.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.3.0\runtimes\unix\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Data.SqlClient.dll` at runtime.

[Update2]
It looks like in System.Data.SqlClient version 4.4.0, it will be fully-managed by default.

Comment: What dou you mean by "use at runtime"? Should I try to load the assembly from the specified file? Will definitely try that. The System.Data.SqlClient.dll was already in the application folder. Could also build a rest web API with basic CRUD operations, or switch to SQLite which works fine on .NET Core :/

Comment: Copy over the `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` with the one from the `unix` directory before running.

Comment: Sweet! lol but, you didn't hear it from me... ;-) Despite the fact that I work for Microsoft, this remains unsupported (for now).

Comment: I faced the same problem today. Adding the UNIX runtime solved it. Can you explain why this happens ? and what do you mean by "fully-managed implementation" ?

Comment: Native libraries (like sni.dll) are specific to a processor (like x86). Managed libraries can run on any processor. There isn't a version of sni.dll for ARM, but the fully-managed version of System.Data.SqClient.dll doesn't use any native libraries like sni.dll.