# Why is my ASP.NET Core database not working in Windows IoT on my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am publishing an ASP.NET Core app/database on windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3. When I try to save data, I get this error message:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.UnmanagedIsTokenRestricted(IntPtr token, Boolean& isRestricted)

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem, as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43310131/entity-framework-core-on-windows-iot-running-on-a-rpi-3-console-application) you can try to copy unix version of dll. for me it just changed into other issue but meaby it will work for you?